# influxdb query group by value

Tags: influxdb

I am new to influxdb and the TICK environment so maybe it is a basic question but I have not found how to do this. I have installed Influxdb 1.7.2, with Telegraph listening to a MQTT server that receives JSON data generated by different devices. I have Chronograph to visualize the data that is being recieved.

JSON data is a very simple message indicating the generating device as a string and some numeric values detected. I have created some graphs indicating the number of messages recieved in 5 minutes lapse by one of the devices.

```
SELECT count("devid") AS "Device" FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."mqtt_consumer" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND "devid"='D9BB' GROUP BY time(5m) FILL(null)
```

As you can see, in this query I am setting the device id by hand. I can set this query alone in a graph or combine multiple similar queries for different devices, but I am limited to previously identifying the devices to be controlled.

Is it posible to obtain the results grouped by the values contained in devid? In SQL this would mean including something like `GROUP BY "devid"`, but I have not been able to make it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "GROUP BY `devid`" if `devid` is a `tag` in measurement scheme. In case of `devid` being the only tag the number of unique values of `devid` tag is the number of time series in `"telegraf"."autogen"."mqtt_consumer"` measurement. Typically it is not necessary to use some value both as tag and field. You can think of a set of tags in a measurement as a compound unique index(key) in conventional SQL database.